# How do I compile a c++ program into a 32-bit executable instead of 64-bit

Tags: c++, compilation, 32-bit

So I am trying to compile a c++ program and have the executable be 32-bit instead of 64-bit. The system (using a program to simulate a system) I want to run it on is 32-bit and seeing as compiling the program yields 64-bit ELF files I cannot run them. I have added the -m32 flag to the makefile and when compiling i get the following errors:

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++

when using sudo apt install -lstdc++ it simply says it cannot find the library. Anybody perhaps able to give me some direction? I am running all of this using remote wsl in visual studio code on a windows 10 machine. Ultimately I just want the compiled executables from this program to be 32-bit ELFs instead of 64-bit.

This is the make file The program im trying to compile is a benchmark suite located here https://github.com/alifahmed/hopscotch. This is the makefile otherwise located in /cpu/2_bandwidth:

````
TARGET =    bandwidth

.PHONY: all clean $(TARGET)

# directories
INC_DIR = ../include
KERN_DIR = ../kernels
CMN_DIR = ../common
OBJ_DIR = obj


# compiler flags ADDED -m32 FLAG
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -m32 -O3 -fopenmp -march=native -I$(INC_DIR) -std=c++14 $(USER_DEFS)


# header files
HEADERS = $(wildcard $(INC_DIR)/*.h)


# src files
SRC = $(wildcard *.cpp) $(wildcard $(KERN_DIR)/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(CMN_DIR)/*.cpp)

# object files
OBJ = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

all: $(TARGET)
    
clean:
    @rm -rf $(OBJ)
    @rm -rf $(TARGET)
    @echo "Cleaned..."
    
%.o: %.cpp $(HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@```
````

Comment: you need to install x32 version of  standard library

Comment: I am sorry if it is a stupid question, but how do I do that? I thought that was what gcc-multilib was.

Comment: it depends on the os. on ubuntu try to search with `apt-cache search libstdc++ | grep 386` or `apt-cache search libstdc++ | grep 686`

Comment: Yes hi @StPiere sry for late reply. I did as you suggested and added the x32 library from the grep. It did move me past the "cannot find lib" issues. Now Ive encountered a new problem where im getting error messages of the type "architecture of input file is incompatible with the i386 output". It is progress though and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

That's easy, just install the 32-bit development libraries

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install gcc-multilib g++-multilib
```

Comment: I already have it. I am still getting the error. at least when running sudo apt install gcc-multilib i get:

gcc-multilib is already the newest version (4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 237 not upgraded.

Comment: Please post your Makefile and tell us which gcc version you're running.

Comment: Have added makefile and my version are:
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609

Comment: Right, g++. Then you need to also install the package "g++-multilib". Updated my answer.

Comment: Yes hi @Tarmo sry for late reply. I had g++ multilib installed as well. Needed to add the i386 architecture. I am now past the cannot find lib problems but have encountered new problems in the form of "input file architecture is incompatible with i386 output". which to my understanding is that some precompiled .o files were done explicitly or implicitly with the -m64 flag.

Comment: Hmm. You're not linking any external libraries?